# VS Code Publish to GitHub, but repository is empty

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, repository, publish

New to GitHub. I have some code on my local computer, which I'd like to put on GitHub. When I use the "Publish to GitHub" function in VS Code, a repository is successfully created on GitHub. However, there is nothing in the repository. I thought all the files will be uploaded to GitHub when I publish it? I tried to do a Push in VS Code, but it says there's nothing to push..

Answer (score 0):

When you create a repository, git creates an empty repo, the files that you want to upload you have to add and commit them to push them.
Remember to be in the current directory where the files are.
By terminal to add the files you can do with:

1. `git add <filename>` or `git <filename1> <filename2>`
   Once you add the files, now you have to commit it or them.
2. `git commit -m "This is the name of my commit"`
   You can write any name for your commit, after you do this step, then you can push to your repo.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't get a chance to try your suggestion, because the problem is solved by itself a day later.

Answer (score 0):

You have to commit your files first. I believe this is how you do it in VS Code:

[image: How to commit in VS Code]

(Click in the "branch" icon on the left and then on the "Commit" checkmark)

Comment: Thanks, I tried your suggestion, but VS Code says "There are no changes to commit."

Comment: You might have opened a different folder than where you git repo is. I recommend watching some "How to use git with VS Code" videos, they will explain it to you better than I can.

Answer (score 0):

[Solved]

The files showed up in the repository a day later. GitHub shows the commit time was yesterday, which is correct, except none of the files was visible at that time.